# Is there any format for official Physiological/Medicine answers?

Tags: physiology, homework, microbiology

Assume you have an exam which has 5 extensive questions and 60 minutes.
You do not have time to cover most if you write everything in essay format.
If you start to write essays, you do not really have time to cover all mechanisms and so on.

I just heard that one student did the exam with by list format, for instance

> sitting -> venous return down & skeletal muscles not working correctly -> trombus.

and then describing relevant mechanisms similarly and combining the their roles shortly.

Another morphology of H. pylori

> Curved (spiral shape), Gram-negative, 2-4 micrometer long, coccoid forms in older cultures,

**Is there any official standard or unofficial accepted way how to answer questions in Physiology/Medicine?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the highly variable nature of such processes and systems, it's unlikely that a common standard is feasible or sensible. In medical questions, a bottom-up order like in your example usually makes sense, starting with the most specific known cause and deriving from there until you arrive at the symptoms. Treatments can branch off or into the order at the point where they apply logically.

If your exam instructions ask for flow text, your question is alreay unnecessary - but if you believe you have the choice, use a note format that is appropriate by common sense. You are essentially creating a diagram, and like any diagram you have to ensure that it is self-contained and comprehensive.

You can shorten the amount of time it takes to write sentences by reducing the literary quality. Of course a well-written text is more pleasing to read and mark, but the main emphasis in your grading will usually be content, meaning that you can afford to form sentences of repetitive structures or lacking logical connection if it is difficult to figure out quickly whether there is one or how to express it etc.

Answer (score 1):

I usually answer in a extensive and descriptive way, and I try to put as much information as possible. If it's a process I usually add a little diagram. If there are lot of attributes to add sometimes I do lists, but usually teachers don't like them an it's easier to find errors or lacks in lists.

There is no standard answer model at least in my University.

Comment: I completely agree with figures about the anatomical structures. They help a lot and help you to think what to answer.